# When using the Code Analysis tools in Visual Studio 2013, is it possible to create my own rules?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

When using the Code Analysis tools in Visual Studio 2013 (C#), is it possible to create my own rules?  I think I can use something like this to help enforce coding conventions.

I found [MSDN this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx) that goes over the process, but the article is five years old and warns that it uses an unsupported feature.  All of my other searching led me to posts showing how to create custom rulesets.  I want to create custom rules however.

Edit: Here are a couple of rules I would create to give you an idea:

- We have our own logging libraries. I'd like a way to detect if the user references log4net, nlog, or some other framework. Or detect if the user tries to roll there own (by checking for variables named logger for instance).

  - A rule could generate a warning that says "*use <company> logger instead*"
- The user manually uses INotifyPropertyChanged

  - A rule will generate a message that says "*use <company> aspect instead*"

Comment: Switch to VS2015 (currently in CTP), which fully supports this using Roslyn analyzers.

Comment: What kind of diagnostics do you need? It is possible that our team can help you and quickly implement it in PVS-Studio. Please email us for details: http://www.viva64.com/en/about-feedback/

Comment: @AndreyCpp: A couple examples of what I'd like might be (1) we have our own logging libraries.  I'd like a way to detect if the user references log4net, nlog, or some other framework.  Or detect if the user tries to roll there own (by checking for variables named `logger` for instance).  The rule could generate a warning that says "use <company> logger instead".  (2) if the user manually uses INotifyPropertyChanged, a rule will generate a message that says "use <company> aspect instead".  These are just some ideas that I'd like to explore.

Comment: @AndreyCpp: I forgot to mention that we are using C#.

Comment: I don't see a question.  You know it is possible, why don't you try it?

Comment: @HansPassant are you asking me?  I put a question in the title of my post.  What do you mean "I don't see a question"?  And what would I try?  Do you mean an old, unsupported feature?  That's not sustainable.

Comment: @user2023861: Sorry. We don't support С#.